# Harmonic analysis on reductive groups over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, harmonic-analysis, reductive-groups

A common way of doing harmonic analysis on (the $\mathbb{R}$-points of) reductive groups over $\mathbb{R}$ seems to be to use results from semisimple groups and "see what happens on the center". Since I want to work in the most general setting of possibly non-split reductive algebraic groups $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$, I would be grateful for some clarifications on what precisely might happen.

There seem to be two candidates for the semisimple group involved. Let $\overline{G}$ be the adjoint group of $G$ (the quotient $G/Z_G$ as algebraic groups, where $Z_G$ is the center of $G$) and then look at the $\mathbb{R}$-points, hence look at the semisimple reductive Lie group $\overline{G}(\mathbb{R})$. On the other hand, one could also look at $G(\mathbb{R}) / Z_G(\mathbb{R})$. If $G$ splits over $\mathbb{R}$, both groups should be isomorphic but in general, the latter should only be a finite index subgroup of $\overline{G}(\mathbb{R})$ (but still their connected components of 1 should be isomorphic).

1. If I want to work with algebraic groups, $\overline{G}(\mathbb{R})$ seems to be the more natural choice but in order to use results from real reductive Lie groups, maybe just taking the quotient by the center directly might be easier?

A first step is to understand Group decompositions for $\overline{G}$ and further, how they relate to the corresponding decompositions of $G$. Let $N$ be the unipotent radical of a minimal parabolic subgroup of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ be the maximal $\mathbb{R}$-split torus in the center of the Levi part of this minimal parabolic subgroup and set $A = S(\mathbb{R})^\circ$. Let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb{R})$ Then we have the Iwasawa decomposition
$$ G(\mathbb{R}) = A N(\mathbb{R}) K $$

As seen above, we have a map $G(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \overline{G}(\mathbb{R}), \ x \mapsto \overline{x}$ with kernel $Z_G(\mathbb{R})$. Denote the same objects as above for the group $\overline{G}$ by $N^1$, $S^1$, $A^1$ and $K^1$. Then we should have
$$ \overline{G}(\mathbb{R}) = A^1 N^1(\mathbb{R}) K^1.$$

2. Is there any way to compare the objects for $G$ and $\overline{G}$?

As far as I understand (see [1]), $K$ should be a finite index subgroup of $K^1$. If $G$ splits over $\mathbb{R}$, then $Z_G$ is itself a split torus and with $A_G = Z_G(\mathbb{R})^\circ$ we should have
$ \overline{G}(\mathbb{R}) \overset{?}{=} G(\mathbb{R})^1 = A_G \backslash G(\mathbb{R}) = (A_G \backslash A) \,  N(\mathbb{R}) K$,
since the unipotent subgroup $N(\mathbb{R})$ should not "see" the center ($G$ is reductive, so there are no unipotent elements in the center of $G$). Here $G(\mathbb{R})^1$ is the intersection of the kernels of the absolute values of all rational characters of $G$. This somehow motivated the above Idea, that working with $G(\mathbb{R}) / Z_G(\mathbb{R})$ might be a good idea.

Further, concerning the Lie-algebra data of both groups. How do they relate? Since $G$ is reductive, its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ should be of the form $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g}) \oplus [ \mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$.

3. Is it true, that $\operatorname{Lie}(\overline{G}(\mathbb{R})) = [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$? If not, is there any way to compare the two?

Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the Lie algebra of $A$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{a}^1$ be the Lie algebra of $A^1$.

4. What can we say about the relation between $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{a}^1$? What about the root data of both groups?

Denote by $\mathfrak{a}_G$ the Lie algebra of $A_G$. Then we have the direct sum decomposition $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}_G \oplus \mathfrak{a}^G$. If I am not mistaken, the second direct summand $\mathfrak{a}^G$ can be identified with the Lie algebra of $A_G \backslash A$, so in the case $G$ is split, this should be equal to $\mathfrak{a}^1$.

Thank you for your time reading this, I would be greateful for any hint in the right direction.

[1] see a post from before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972218/adjoint-group-of-a-reductive-group - The question there had a different twist and was maybe a bit more basic.

Comment: Why not take the Lie group attached to the derived group of $G$ (or even the simply connected cover of the derived group of $G$).? If you want to deduce statements about reductive groups from statements about semisimple groups, these seem better choices.

Comment: The final goal is to understand $A_G \, G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash G(\mathbb{A}) / K_f \cong \coprod_i (\Gamma_i \backslash G(\mathbb{R})^1)$, $K_f \subset G(\mathbb{A}_{\operatorname{fin}})$ a compact open subgroup. ($G$ now a group over $\mathbb{Q}$, the rest as above.) So from a handwavy point of view, the group $\overline{G}(\mathbb{R})$ seems closer to $G(\mathbb{R})^1$, which is not semisimple in the non-split case, than the derived subgroup or its simply connected cover.